# PHP not locating mcrypt while using MAMP

Tags: mac, php, mamp

I'm using MAMP on a MAC. And in the php info page on MAMP, it says that mcrypt is enabled. However, when I run "php -m" on the terminal, I can't find mcrypt between the php modules.

Any advice??

Comment: Does the provided answer below answer your question?  If so can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MAMP relies on the php package installed in Terminal (or in OS X for that matter). MAMP uses it's own php version located at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3`

The modules are in the folder I noted above in a subfolder called **/modules**. You would have to manually get mcrypt in the modules folder for MAMP to work with mcrypt.